# UITableView crash: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a UITableView which basically contains a certain amount of items + 1 default item that will always be there like this. When only the default item is there, there isn't any issues. Once the tableView is created and contains more than the default item, the app crashes with this index out of bounds error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Code:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame scene:(Group *)scene{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    cardList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(Card *card in [[AppDataManager getInstance]getCards]){
        if(card.type.intValue == 2){
            if(![card.properties containsObject:scene.id]){
                [cardList addObject:card];
            }
        }
    }
    self.scene = scene;
    [self setDataSource:self];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self setBounces:NO];
    [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, (44 * (cardList.count + 1)))];
    [self registerClass:[AddSceneToCardListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"addSceneToCardCell"];
    return self;
}

-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return cardList.count + 1;
}

-(AddSceneToCardListCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    AddSceneToCardListCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addSceneToCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.row == cardList.count){
        //Default row
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_add.png"]];
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"New card"];
    }else{
        Card *card = [cardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_scene_icon.png"]];
        [cell.textLabel setText:card.title];
    }
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return cell;
}
```

Using my epic NSLog skills, I figured out the crash happens when the app arrives at the dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier line. It seems to create the first non-default cell without any issue, but the default cell crashes.

stack:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x20185e, 0x333c5df0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x333c5df0 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x33444cc6 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 62
    frame #2: 0x33361908 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 76
    frame #3: 0x3266a9c8 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 88
    frame #4: 0x32684670 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 268
    frame #5: 0x32d49f24 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 192
    frame #6: 0x32681de2 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 78
    frame #7: 0x326818ae libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 102
    frame #8: 0x32d49dd2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 42
    frame #9: 0x245b629c CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 632
    frame #10: 0x245b6012 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    frame #11: 0x2c087200 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 136
    frame #12: 0x27d82a08 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1440
  * frame #13: 0x0014260c Application`main(argc=1, argv=0x003f5afc) + 108 at main.m:14
```

**EDIT**
I sort of figured it out. The crash seems to happen because of the delegate class I set, so it has nothing to do with the code above. Everybody thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: try to use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addSceneToCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; instead of [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addSceneToCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]

Comment: Nope, from the exception it looks like problem is in `Card *card = [cardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. First you have one more `}`. But not sure why you have problem with objectAtIndex.

Comment: @user3779315 Already tried that

Comment: @LiborZapletal The } is just a typo that isn't in the actual code. I am completely sure the issue is on the dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier: line.

Comment: Please try this,

`AddSceneToCardListCell *cell = (AddSceneToCardListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addSceneToCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

You need to type cast the cell. Because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` returns UITableViewCell object, might be its getting conflicted.

Comment: I would try to add check `if (indexPath.row < cardList.count) { ... [cardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; .. }` to be sure

Comment: where is call stack? You can get it in two ways. If crash will happen and program will stop in `main` function, type in debugger console: `bt`. Or add exception break point and when it is hit copy call stack of thread with exception from left view of Xcode (this method is better since you can inspect values of variables).

Comment: `[self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addSceneToCardCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` should it not be `tableView` instead of self? Or are you using a custom method?

Answer (score 1):

Exception indicates that you have an index range problem. This has nothing common with `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier`!

Pleas provide  call stack? You can get it in two ways:

- If crash will happen and program will stop in main function, type in debugger console: bt.
- Or add exception break point and when it is hit copy call stack of thread with exception from left view of Xcode (this method is better since you can inspect values of variables).

I'm suspecting that you are handling adding or removing items from table in wrong way and that is why `indexPath.row` give you a value outside of expected range.
Check this value when exception is raised (using second method for call stack inspection).

Show us code related with "New card" functionality.

Comment: I added the stack trace. The new card cell doesn't do anything yet. I am just trying to create a tableView first. The weirdest part is, I have pretty much the same code somewhere else in the application and it seems to run just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to you array data structure before creating it. Try to move the allocation in `viewDidLoad:` method.

Answer (score 0):

in numberOfRowsInSection you return cardList+1;

If suppose cardList has 10 items in it. you return 11 items to be displayed.

So cellForRowAtIndexPath is responsible to return 11 cells. Indeed. No issues. But problem is

```
    // Card = 10 cards total
    // instructing table to load 11 cards (existing card(10) + 1)
    // Index will start from 0(1st card) to 10(11th card).

    //  for 11th row  index is 10 == 11 count ==> NO
    // This will never execute, so it will go to its else loop, 
    // where the crash is happening
    if(indexPath.row == cardList.count){ 

        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_add.png"]];
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"New card"];
    }else{
        // get "11th item/10th index" in the card list.
        // cardList says, "Oh I have only 10 cards, I knew upto 0-9 indexes."  
        // "I will try to get it & access something bad & crash."

        Card *card = [cardList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //You make me to get Crashed.

        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_scene_icon.png"]];
        [cell.textLabel setText:card.title];
    }
```

So this line cardList.count/indexPath.row should be adjusted.

```
    if(indexPath.row == cardList.count){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return [cardList count];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if([cardList count] > 0 && [cardList count] > indexPath.row)
{
  /// code
}
```